# Разница в методах обхода массива

Tags: массивы, php

Есть ли у такого метода обхода массива преимущество над обычным foreach ?

```
    $parts = str_split($pattern);
    while ($part = current($parts))
```

**UPDATE**
От сюда [github](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Util/Url.php)

Comment: `foreach` специализированная конструкция для обхода массива и прекрасно справляется со своей задачей. Аналогом является использование `while` в сочетании `list`+`each`. Ну а приведенный подход к разбору строки сразу вызывает сомнение, ибо при `$pattern = '1230321';` цикл закончится на элементе `$parts` со значением `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за вопрос, не задумывался раньше!

В O'Reilly "Programming PHP" [пишут](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch05_07.htm), что `foreach` **создает копию** массива, и работает с ней, поэтому можно смело стирать/добавлять элементы внутри цикла. Но съедается лишняя память.

Поэтому при работе с крупными массивами (а php относительно прожорливо использует память при организации массивов), предпочтительнее итерировать через `current` / `next`, которые работают непосредственно с оригиналом массива.

**upd**. [подробный ответ на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works/14854568#14854568) (на англ.). Array копируется, но не всегда; `foreach` использует независимые указатели, и нормально отработает два вложенных `foreach($a..){ foreach($a..){ .. }}`, в то время, как `each/current/next' работают с единым внутренним указателем, и вложенность внесет сумятицу. В общем, читайте развернутый ответ на SO.

Comment: С успехом можно указать ссылку на элемент в `foreach`.

[`ideone.com`][1]

[1]: http://ideone.com/g8JFTc

Comment: @ua6xh при чем тут ссылка из `foreach`? Речь о больших массивах и экономии памяти.

Comment: @sergiks, Интереса ради даже проверил потребление памяти на небольшом массиве в 10к элементов по 1 байту. Проверял 3 конструкции:

    while ($part = current($parts)) {next($parts);}

    while (list($vv, $vn) = each($parts)) {}

    foreach ($parts as $vn => $part) {}

Разницу в потреблении памяти выявить не удалось - ничтожно мала. А вот с точки зрения скорости работы `foreach` в 5 раз быстрее `current / next` и в 10 раз быстрее `list + each`.
Да и в официальной документации нет ничего ни о каких копиях массивах при использовании `foreach`. Да и приведенная Вами статья рассказывает не о том

Comment: @sergiks, при том, что не будет никакого копирования при итерировании значений по ссылке.

Comment: По чем купил, за то продаю. Процитированное издание книги 2003-го года. С тех пор php «немного»  изменился. Найдите и приведите более актуальные данные.

@Равнодушный спасибо, что не поленились сравнить. Есть ли под рукой старая версия php? Интересно сравнить.

Comment: @Равнодушный [на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works/14854568#14854568) подробно исследовали эту же тему. `foreach` НЕ является аналогом `while( list..each)`: вложенные два `foreach($a..){ foreach($a..){  }}` отработают независимо, в то время, как `each/current/next` используют единый внутренний указатель.

Comment: @sergiks, с точки зрения результата - является. А про реализацию я ничего и не говорил.

Comment: @sergiks @Равнодушный есть два способа использования foreach, один копирует массив, второй (передача по ссылке) нет. Ничего неправильного никто из вас не сказал, просто можно и так, и так.

Comment: @Fike, нет копирования массива, есть создание двух переменных со значениями ключ=>значение из элемента, на который установлен указатель, которые в процессе обхода постоянно пересоздаются, а указатель смещается вперед. Что, собственно и дает конструкция `while (list($vv, $vn) = each($parts)) {}`. Аналогично можем и тут ссылки прописать - сути это не меняет. Массив ни в одном из примеров не "задваивается" в памяти.

Comment: @Равнодушный, да, кажется я заврался